# Object Movement on HTML Canvas, asteroids

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is more of a movement physics question. But I have a slight bug that I haven't been able to figure out in an Asteroids game I'm making. For my ship, I have a thrust function that is activated when you press the up arrow:

```
let rotationAngle = 0;

function thrust() {
  velocity[0] += Math.cos(rotationAngle);
  velocity[1] += Math.sin(rotationAngle);
}
```

This is supposedly supposed to move the ship forward.
The update function that is called in my game loop is:

```
function update() {
  spec.center.x += velocity[0] * .1;
  spec.center.y += velocity[1] * .1; //.1 is the acceleration
  if (spec.center.x > MyGame.graphics.canvas.width) spec.center.x = 0; //wrapping
  if (spec.center.x < 0) spec.center.x = MyGame.graphics.canvas.width;
  if (spec.center.y > MyGame.graphics.canvas.height) spec.center.y = 0;
  if (spec.center.y < 0) spec.center.y = MyGame.graphics.canvas.height;
}
```

It makes it so that the ship will keep floating when the thrust button is released. This all seems to work ok, except for the fact that instead of moving up, it moves to the right, i.e., if I'm pressing the thrust button to make it move forward, it moves sideways.

Am I missing something simple here? If I need to give more details about rendering and all that I will gladly do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Without a [mcve], it's pretty difficult to visualize/reproduce the problem and speak about what might be causing it. Offhand, though, your functions are manipulating values outside their scope, which is unsafe and makes your program state difficult to reason about.

Comment: An angle of 0 degrees is toward the right (along the x axis). If you created the image of your ship so that it is pointing up when the image is not rotated, you will accelerate toward the side. If this is the problem, you can either rotate the image by a quarter turn or add the rotation when calculating your thrust.

Comment: @aptriangle how could I do that with the rotation on the thrust? I've tried a few ways without success. I can also confirm that just rotating the image doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Subtract Math.PI/2 inside both Math.sin and Math.cos